# Inductor without inductance

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, ethernet, phy

I am trying to find the right component for this inductor. It doesn't show inductance which is bit confusing for me. Which part should I pick for this if I wanted to use it on my PCB?

it's from
NUCLEO-H723ZZG

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely can't measure the inductance as it is very small.

It's not an inductor.

The part is a ferrite bead, with 600 ohms impedance at 100 MHz.

You will find the exact part number from the Nucleo board BOM list.

Comment: great stuff, that's all I need. I wasn't aware there's BOM file for each Nucleo board ! Thank you

Comment: Well, it'll have inductance, most likely 1-2uH in the <1MHz range. Some inductance remains up to higher frequencies, but it's balanced by resistance above a few to 10 MHz. (Impedance curves can be looked up in most datasheets.)